# How to switch between editors with shortcuts

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut

I'm tired of pulling out windows to get the UV editor or pull down a menu in the screen sets.
Is there a shortcut, with one key, to get my 3D view to UV editor/node editor?

I have not found a way to edit shortcuts that way.

Answer (score 23):

**Yes**.

There are several screenlayout presets which are selectable from the info header:

[image]

You can also cycle through them with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>← Left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→ Right arrow</kbd>.

You can also define your own presets by clicking the **+** next to the drop down and then arranging the screen how you want it.

In order to keep your presets whenever you start up blender, you'll have to save the startup .blend by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. Note that this will save *everything* as default, including user preferences, view orientation, objects, materials, etc.

---

There are also shortcuts to turn the current editor under the mouse into another editor. For example, press:

- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> for a *Logic editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> for a *Node editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> for a *Python console*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> for a *3D view*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> for a *Graph editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> for a *Properties editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> for a *NLA editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> for an *Outliner*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> for a *UV/image editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> for a *Text editor*
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> for a *Dope sheet*

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between the Geonodes editor, Compositor, and Shader editor?

Comment: @AnsonSavage Pressing `Shift+F3` multiple times cycles between them, but if you want to have separate shortcuts for each, it can likely be achieved with a little python scripting

Answer (score 5):

Just rename your screen layout presets like Default and Default Node so they are alphabetically next to each other, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> is one keystoke to node editor and same back.

You can also change the shortcuts from user preferences > input > screen > set screen
So its really one keystroke.