# Why Can't i get back to the normal screen layout?

Tags: scene

My screen layout in one blend won't go back to normal. Even if I go to the tile area there is no bar for the different screen areas like uv editing. in the right hand corner where file and window is supposed to be, there is the object mode, rotate,scale and transform option. Look at the picture[look at the arrow

[image]

Comment: You might find this useful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17935/how-to-switch-between-editors-with-shortcuts

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus or this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it I'd say you have several (5, to be exact) 3d-View Windows. Selct one of the cube icons, I would suggest the second counting from left to right and set it from 3d view to "Info". Then you can change between the presets.

[image]

[image]