# Accidentally hit "toggle full screen", How do I exit?

Tags: interface, node-editor

I'm stuck in full screen in the node editor. Escape isn't working, and I have no menus and no idea how to leave except to quit Blender and reopen the program.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Space worked for me on OSX

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To toggle out of full screen area (what I think you did) press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, or move your mouse to the top right corner and click the button that appears.
Here I start in full screen area, notice the button that appears in the top right corner.
[image: animated gif showing button to exit full screen area]

If you just maximized the window you can get back to the normal view a number of ways.

- Click the "*Back To Previous*" button in the info window at the top.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

If you toggled blender into full screen view press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>.

---

Update
**For blender 2.8** the shortcuts are

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle maximize

or

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
 to toggle Full Screen.

[image]

Comment: Yup, it was `Alt`+`F10` indeed :) Thanks for the extra info too. That's helpful.

Comment: Life savior (on MacOSX)

Comment: Alt+f10 always escapes me. Best fullscreen mode for sculpting. Thank you for the comprehensive list!

Comment: Another solution: Press `F3` and search after "Toggle" and you'll find "Toggle Fullscreen Area"

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to toggle panel full screen mode in blender via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>  :)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response :) but shift+space didn't seem to do anything and I wound up quitting and reopening Blender - it looks like alt+fn+F10 will toggle both in and out of full screen node editor on a Mac laptop. Sorry for the complete noobness...

Answer (score 2):

On Mac none of the above worked, I got it toggling on and off with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: `Ctrl + Space` *or* `Ctrl + Alt + Space` works on OSX.

Comment: ...but on my Blender 3.0 I must use `Cmd` instead:  `Cmd + Alt + Fn + Space`.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>**ALT+F11**</kbd> to toggle Full Screen.

Comment: It's not Blender, that is in fullscreen mode, it's the Node Editor. F11 is the shortcut to UV/Image Editor.

Comment: As the edit corrected the shortcut for toggle full screen is **Alt F11** not F11