# How to type in script editor window when mouse cursor is elsewhere?

Tags: scripting

I'm very new to blender, using it for robotics, so primarily drawing using python very little hand-drawing.

When I am typing in the script editing window in Blender (2.76b in Ubuntu) and my mouse cursor drifts outside this window (worst is the viewport window), the ability to type into the editor window halts. I have to manually push my mouse cursor back in, even if the text cursor (|) is still in the editor window. Is there a way to change this default behavior?

It is particularly annoying if I accidentally type a hotkey (e.g., Z) that changes some basic behavior in the viewport, and I don't know what I did. This is becoming very frustrating and inefficient.

I assume this is also a feature, so you can go do some quick hotkey stuff in the viewport while working on scripting, but I would really like to let my mouse cursor and text editing cursor be in different places, while editing text. That is, I want the text cursor to take all my keyboard events, as is the default in all my other applications.

I have searched online for an answer, posted at blender forum and gotten no response yet:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?402785-How-to-type-in-script-editor-window-when-mouse-cursor-elsewhere

Comment: Indeed this "feature" of blender (mouse position sensitive context) is **very** annoying in the text editor. Alas I do not know of a way to change it. UVed.

Comment: it's the way blender works, it tracks the mouse to know what editor is active and what context will receive keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: I guess I could just maximize the text editor window (stretch it WAAY to the right edge, maybe into my second monitor), minimize the viewport :) Seems draconian, but if it works...

Comment: root I can see this being really useful for all the gui stuff, where your life tends to revolve around the mouse cursor, but for scripting it can be very annoying.

Comment: I wonder how blender got this bad, how terrible things like this are baked into the fabric of this editor, like what sort of decisions lead to nightmares like this?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a workaround but if you *Toggle Fullscreen Area* <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, then you can type in the text editor with the mouse cursor outside of blender!

[image: animated gif]

See [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55995/2217) for other options for maximizing windows in blender.
However full screen area is the only one that works completely, simply maximizing the text editor the header and info bar still get in the way.

Comment: In my system  (ubuntu 16) alt-f10 just brings up wireless network menu, but ctrl-up arrow does make current window take up the whole blender main window. Unfortunately even then I still can't type when the mouse is outside the window, like you are doing in the gif. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: well either change the system shortcut or change blender's shortcut, because as I said in my answer "full screen area is the only one that works completely."