# Active window regardless of mouse position?

Tags: scripting, workspaces

I'm scripting so I have several windows open, and there is a feature that is quite bothering. I'll explain it with an example: say I want to copy a  line of code. I use the mouse to select it but in doing so, the cursor ends slightly outside the window in use. I hit ctrl+C but as the mouse was in another window, nothing gets copied. After I try to paste it elsewhere and nothing happens, I have to go back and make sure the cursor stays in the first window while copying.

Is there a way to have an active window that does not depend on the position of the cursor? Maybe activating a window with a click?

Comment: I don't think this is the right community for this question, not sure where this would fit better though.

Comment: Related (possible dupe) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57740/how-to-type-in-script-editor-window-when-mouse-cursor-is-elsewhere.  My wireless mouse has the tendency to wander, making this issue very annoying at times.  Consider using a dedicated text editor instead. My editor of choice is `nvim`.  It has a python backend so open buffers can be "squirted" to and from with minimal code. See also the "script stub" template for running external scripts within blender.

Comment: "I have several windows open" <== I believe it is called "Areas" inside Blender, or do you really mean "window" (usually 1 per application)?