# Wrong View Mode/ All Menus gone

Tags: modeling

I somehow suddenly landed in a total different environment on blender, most of my menus are gone, I just want to go back to the normal default view with all menus. I saved the file and opened it again, but the same problem appears. I really hope someone can help...
[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/accidentally-hit-toggle-full-screen-how-do-i-exit. Maybe you pressed Alt+F10, press it again

Comment: try Ctrl + Right Arrow

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like you created a floating window.  Try closing the window (click the red or yellow button) to see if your regular workspace is underneath.