# How to toggle header visibility while 3D aera is maximized?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

When areas are tiled, the 3D editor area looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to maximize this area to fill the whole window. I used `Alt-F10`, then `T` and `N` to get the tools pane and the properties pane back:

[image]

I couldn't find a menu/hot key to toggle the header visibility. How do I get the header back?

---

I saw: [How to toggle the menu bar back?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48428/) which doesn't provide an answer.

Alternatively, I could have used `Ctl-Up` to get this:

[image]

But how could I hide the `infos` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle header = <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Might interfere with Nvidia default shadowplay global key-bindings.

---

Alternatively:

- Create another screen layout besides your *Default* layout.
- Close/merge all the areas you don't want
- Enter/exit this layout using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-></kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd><-</kbd>