# Fastest way to switch to and from viewports?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a faster way to swap viewports than to click the "current editor type for this area" button and find the thing we want and click it....?

I waste way too much time trying to find the thing I need, its not intuitive to me even after practice. I wanna quickswap the properties tab to the graph editor and back again....and to the uv editor and the node editor etc...

There hotkeys somewhere or a good addon?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17935/how-to-switch-between-editors-with-shortcuts. Also it's beneficial to use saved screen layouts

Comment: You can click on the button, then type a key to select one of the options. Each entry in the list has a single underlined letter. If you click on the menu, then press that key on your keyboard, it will change the editor mode immediately. N for node graph, E for UV/image editor, G for graph editor etc. I use this all the time and it's pretty fast.

Comment: what/how did u search to find that thread "how to switch between editors with shortcuts" ? I searched but couldn't find anything earlier. @Tavi: those are cool, not sure what some of them are though like for properties. I think the shift+f1...f2..f3 method in the other thread is gonna be eventually preferred so long as I can somehow memorize them though :)

Comment: The best workflow tools are whatever works for you. You might also want to check out pie menus, which give you radial menus for your tools.

Comment: ya, i ended up rebinding shift+f7 etc to f1 f2 f3...to easily pop up properties, uv edtir, and graph editor. the pie thing is cool i'm messing aroudn with it now, might keep them on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes first at the top menu where it says default click the plus and name it graph editor now bottom left of blender change window to graph editor  Hold CNTRL on Keyboard and use left or right arrow keys to cycle threw work spaces
repeat this step adding all to the list. when your done setting up click file and save as  MyDefault.blend to desktop you will now have a new blender icon on desktop named MyDefault simply dubble click it and use as your default start up now every time you start up blender simply press CNTRL and arrow keys to switch work spaces.